# Calculating Electron Relaxation time in Nanostructures

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, electronic-band-theory

Is there a method to calculate the electron relaxation time in nano-structures?

It would be nice to avoid methods such as DFT since the number of atoms is high and I do not have much computational resources. I already have the band structure and the eigen values calculated through DFT though.